# Page.Session not set to an instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls, htmltextwriter

I'm having trouble understanding how `Page.Request.QueryString` and `Page.Session` works.  How would I assign a `name` to this `string`

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "proc_UserBids";
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 1000;
        string str = this.Page.Request.QueryString["name"] == null ? this.Page.Session["name"].ToString() : ((object)this.Page.Request.QueryString["name"]).ToString();
        if (!(str == ""))
        {
      //Do Something
       }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
 string str = this.Page.Request.QueryString["name"] == null ? this.Page.Session["name"].ToString() : ((object)this.Page.Request.QueryString["name"]).ToString();
```

Comment: You neither has query string nor session with key "name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set some value to `session` called `name`.

Example (vb.net) :

```
Session.Add("name","some string")
```

Then You can use this `Session("name")` in any page.

For example in some other page : `Dim str As String = Session("name")`

If You want pass some value using `QueryString`, from one to another page then use below code.
Example :
deafult.aspx

```
Response.Redirect("otherpage.aspx?name=Some string")
```

otherpage.aspx (code behind) :

```
Request.QueryString("name")
```

I hope so this is what You need.